# Using Multiple Versions of ArcGIS API for JS in Same Application

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

We've a large web based GIS application running which uses an older version of ArcGIS API (v3.7) for JS. The ArcGIS JSAPI v3.7 is lacking some functionality which are available in v3.15. Now I also need to include ArcGIS JS API v3.15 for a specific function.

Changing API version for whole application is not an option.

So, Is it possible to include some of the modules from v3.15 for a specific function and destroy when that function is executed?

Scenario:

```
//code uses v3.7
// ....
// ...
function executeLatestFeature() {
  // need to use some functions from v3.15
  //... 
}
//code uses v3.7
```

Comment: It would be risky to use both versions, especially because the JS API references other libraries. The JS API doesn't have the same no conflict functionality as something like jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

For one, if you were to load both API's, you would end up with a namespace collision with Dojo's Define and Require.

For two, the API is obfuscated (not human readable) making it difficult to extract just the parts you need. Even if you could, there may be dependencies in that module preventing you from using it with an older API.

Comment: Good explanation! Thanks! Any workaround do you've?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not recommended at all Rene Rubalcava did a good walkthrough of how to do this

http://odoe.net/blog/void-your-arcgis-api-for-javascript-warranty/